# Commutability to prove one matrix represented as polynomial of another

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

For two square matrices $A$ and $B$. If $B$ commutes with all the matrices that commutes with $A$, prove that $B$ can be represented as a polynomial of $A$. It is very complicated if we do it by matrix analysis directly. Can someone give me an easy prove in some special algebraic way?

Comment: The result you are interested in is called a *double centralizer theorem*. Try googling for this. I doubt there is an "easy" proof (but this depends on what you call easy).

Comment: @T.Jassen you are right. Removing the answer.

Comment: @Strants You example does not fit my question,if $A=I$,then $B$ should commute with all the matrix of the same order.So $B$ must be of the form $λI$,satisfies the result.

Comment: @zhoraster I've googled it,but I found no one of the condition satisfies it..As $A$ changes,how can the ring $K[A]$ always be simple, so that the theorem can be used?Or some other condition fit it?

Comment: @T.Jassen, your question is first lemma [**here**](https://ysharifi.wordpress.com/2011/01/30/a-double-centralizer-theorem-for-central-simple-algebras/). I don't know how it's proved, but it must be standard, so the proof can be probably found in textbooks.

Comment: @T.Jassen You're right, my mistake.